# Beginner Python : How to save output in the same location and with a different name?

Tags: python, logging, output

I would like to save the output in the same location as the input but using a different, but still related, name.

*Minimal Example:*
This script searches for lines containing the string "NFS" in the input file. Then, it prints the results to another file.
I would like to save the print result to an output file in the same location as the input file but using a different name like "inputfilename.out.csv".

Here is the code :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1] 

out = open(fname.out.csv, "w") #this doesn't work but this is the idea

with open(fname) as file:
    reader = file.readlines()
    for line in reader:
        if "NFS" in line:
            print(line, file = out)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concatenation to add ".out.csv" to the end of your string.

```
out = open(fname + ".out.csv", "w")
```

If the input filename is "inputfilename", then the output will be "inputfilename.out.csv". This may be undesirable behavior if the input filename already has an extension. Then "inputfilename.csv" will become "inputfilename.csv.out.csv". In which case, you may wish to use `os.path` to construct the new name.

```
import os.path
filename = "inputfilename.csv"
root, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
output_filename = root + ".out" + extension
print output_filename
```

Result:

```
inputfilename.out.csv
```

Comment: `'{}.out.csv'.format(fname)` is better than string concatenation; which should be avoided.

Comment: I agree that `format` is generally more readable than concatenation when it comes to composing strings. However, for the simple case of adding a single value to the end of a string, `+` is just as comprehensible.

Comment: Is it, though? [my tests](http://pastebin.com/hukDuDmj) indicate that `format` is slower.

Comment: I searched complicated but it was just simple...thx for your help. I've just see that output have blank lines and I don't know why, maybe  you have a trick for that ?

Comment: It could be because `print` adds a newline to the end of everything it prints, but `line` already has a newline at the end of it. You could avoid this by doing `print(line.rstrip(), file = out)` or `print(line, file = out, end="")`

Comment: yes you right, blank lines are well removed with your code thx

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to extract extension:

```
import os

name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
output_filename = name + ".out" + ext
```

Or if you want to change the name completely, you could use [`os.path.dirname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) to get the parent directory:

```
import os

dirpath = os.path.dirname(fname)
output_filename = os.path.join(dirpath, "outputfile.txt")
```

Comment: Also a good way to do the job, thx for your time and attention